# Good approach to create a WCF service for Windows Phone application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating an application for Windows Phone 8.1 SL. This application needs to use a WCF service, because it is based on MySQL database.

I know that Service implements interfaces. For example one of my interface (IUser) would have methods like registering and logging. Another interface (IProduct) would have methods like getting: product names, prices and something else connected with products. Another interface (IShop) would have methods like getting shop names, etc. Another (ICustomer) would handle methods connected with customers. And there would be a few more interfaces...

And now should I implement all of these in this one Service.svc? Is it a good approach? If I would do that there would be many methods in this one service. This is the first time then I use WCF for a more extensive application.

This is only my opinion, but I want to do it neatly with a good patterns so please give me some tips how it should be done.

Comment: `And now should I implement all of these in this one Service.svc?` You can't do that. Each service requires a contract, which is an interface exposing available methods to the client. If you have multiple contract interfaces as you described, you'd need a service for each.

Comment: Oh okay I get it. But is there a sense of making few services in this case? Maybe just create one interface which will handle all of those methods?

Comment: @XardasLord - It makes much more sense to separate the different concerns (User, Product, Shop and Customer) into their own services then to roll them all up into one giant service.  A call to a web service is a call to a web service - the most expensive part will be in creating the proxy (if you're using SOAP - and if you are, take a look at WebAPI unless you have a real need for SOAP) - but once the proxy is created you can cache it for reuse.  Or use `ChannelFactory<T>` and then just generate communication channels as needed.

Comment: @Tim Agreed. Unless of course there is some admin interface in which case it is better to keep it as a separate service with possibly different protocols and security models

Comment: @XardasLord - _"This application **needs** to use a **WCF service**, because it is based on **MySQL database**"_ - why would the choice of DB tech dictate the choice of communications API?

Comment: @MickyDuncan No it doesn't. I just want to use WCF service, because I think it's a good idea to use WCF when I need a database connection in my Windows Phone application, isn't it? Because in WP I can't connect to remote database directly by import MySQL connector. So I want to use WCF to do that.

Comment: @XardasLord Sure but your question seems to imply that.  You could always use REST